# Ubuntu 20.04 GUI on HP DL380 G7 crash on login

Tags: 20.04, login, hp, gui

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 server on an HP DL380 G7.
After installing the GUI (ubuntu-desktop) and reboot, I get a very sluggish login screen which crashes (presents with a white screen stating "Oh no! Something has gone wrong").
I am trying to login with the sudo user created during the installation.

Server is a Xeon E5649 2.5ghz (I think that is the speed), 60gb ram, 2.8TB disk. Disk arrangement is a single 2.3TB raid array mounted on root.

Comment: Does your system meet the minimum requirements for GNOME?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  (esp. video requirements; eg. 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB) as many rack mounted servers are intended for headless operation and not for use as desktops.

Comment: There should be something in `/var/log/syslog` that is showing what the problem is. You may have to boot with the Live USB stick to access it. One question: What RAID level are you using? Ubuntu does not like booting from a RAID5 device.

Comment: Matigo, using hardware raid 1+0. there are a total of 8 600gb drives.

Comment: guiverc, very possible it doesn't meet the minimum. When the DL380 G7 was current, 256mb video would have been unheard of in a server. Using the onboard video. Not a particular fan of using a GUI for a server, but given all instructions I have found for using Virtualbox requires a gui, that is what has put me here.

Comment: Guiverc answered the issue. Switched to a lite desktop gui and was able to launch it.

Comment: @Mike Which desktop did you use? XFCE? i3? MATE?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, I don't believe it's compatible with the G7, looking at the approved hardware for Ubuntu, the last version was Trusty Tahr.

https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201403-14898